Check Modified Date on AWS S3 Object using c# .Net SDK Ver3
I wrote an AWS S3 lastModified-conditional upload/download class a few years back in Java.  Now I need to do the same thing in C#.  My Java code is SDK v1.  The current AWS Java SDK is v2. .Net is SDK v3. I haven't been able to find many samples for extracting the lastModified date from an S3 object.  But from what I can find, it appears that AWS is suggesting totally different solutions in v1, v2, and v3 with ObjectMetaData for a while that apparently has disappeared and replaced by ObjectAttributes.  The google AI assistant says to use HeadRequest, but I can't seem to find it in the AWS v3 docs.  And the objects that the are documented in the AWS v3 SDK  for .Net give me not-found errors in Visual Studio.  I understand code evolution and deprecation. But I thought deprecated classes/solutions typically would hang around for a release or two. However at the moment, I can't get VS to even find all of the classes/methods for any of the recommended solutions from any SDK version including v3.
I'm sure there's a clear, simple answer.  But with all of the completely different solutions that don't seem to ever state what SDK versions they work on and which versions they don't work on... I'm just need some help unwinding all of this.  As far as I can tell, I've got the latest v3 SDK and all of the latest .net packages installed (and VS 2022)
Here's what 'appears' to be the latest solution using objects and method defined in the SDK v3 docs. But VS says they are all undefined, including the GetObjectAttributes method on the AmazonS3Client object.  Can someone please either explain what I'm doing wrong with this code, or just simply post code that should be used now (and will work).  I've spent way more time on this than I was expecting.  Thanks.
using Amazon.S3.Model;
public DateTime getLastModified(String bucketName, String keyName)
{
    var request = new GetObjectAttributesRequest
    {
        BucketName = bucketName,
        Key = keyName
    };
    GetObjectAttributesResponse response = getS3Client().GetObjectAttributes(request);
    return( response.LastModified);
}

